# Is there a way to use saxon to pull the timezone from a datetime field?

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, saxon

I'm doing some XSL transformations on an XML timestamp element:

```
<LastModifiedDateTimeStamp>2017-03-03T12:23:59.044Z</LastModifiedDateTimeStamp>
```

I'm trying to pull out the time using this following saxon function:

```
format-dateTime(LastModifiedDateTimeStamp, '[H01][m01][Z001]')
```

I'd like to pull just the values so it looks something like this:

> 2017030301223044

However, `format-datetime` defaults to using a "+" sign and my result always looks like this:

> 201703031223+000.

Does anyone know how to pull out just the timezone value?

Comment: What happens if you omit `[Z001]` from the second argument, the picture string? Do you get the wanted result then?

Comment: This is confusing. First, the result of applying your code is not what you claim. And it seems you want to **remove** the timezone, not "pull" it. Also you say you want "*to pull out the time*" - but your expected result includes the year, month and day, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given:

```
<LastModifiedDateTimeStamp>2017-03-03T12:23:59.044Z</LastModifiedDateTimeStamp>
```

the following expression:

```
format-dateTime(LastModifiedDateTimeStamp, '[Y0001][M01][D01][H01][m01][s01][f001]')
```

will return:

```
20170303122359044
```

which is slightly different from what you posted, but I believe it's correct.

Comment: Hi, I accidentally left out the part the pulled out the year/month/day part but using f001 worked! Thank you!

Comment: Note that "044" in your example is not the timezone, it is the number of milliseconds in the seconds part of the time. Perhaps this is what confused you - it certainly confused me that you were asking about the timezone, but seemed to want something different.